# Field value fetch when field name is not known

Tags: json, node.js, forms

I am using a form builder using which my admin side can create forms and store it as JSON. They are rendered dynamically when the client accesses these forms. When the client submits the form at the back end I need to get the value of all the fields.

Currently I am trying to do this as follows:(Node Server)

```
router.post('/increase', function (req, res, next) {

    req.session.counter++;

    var ans = req.body;

    console.log(ans+" this got printed");

    res.redirect('docfill');


});
```

I cannot specify a name after **req.body** as i dont know the field name due to the dynamic nature of the forms.

The console prints **[Object object]**. The currently rendered form has a date field I need. And if I put it through JSON.stringify() it prints **{}**. Is my fetched data coming out to be blank? Could it be a problem with using the data field.

**EDIT**
its not because the filed is a date type, dosnt work with text either

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons for this:

1. You have not installed/required the `bodyParser` module.
2. In your form tag you're using the `enctype` attribute as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Reason for this being you're not using any module for handling the `multipart/form-data` type which is unreadable by the browser. Use `enctype="application/json"` instead.

Comment: i have the body parser module installed and i have not used enctype in my form

Comment: can you update your question with the html of your input field/s?

Comment: my html is generated and rendered dynamically by a JQuery function that accepts a JSON input, so there isnt any actual HTML i can provide. I assure you the field types are the standard types we use in a HTML form.

Comment: Have you added a ```name``` attribute to the form field and then tried accessing it by ```req.body.name```?

Comment: The forms are rendered dynamically so i isnt possible for me to know the name of the field i am pulling, yes all the fields have a name but that was automatically assigned to them when they were created at the backed end using the form builder. The purpose my question here is to pull all the field data such that i dont have to worry about the field names, only get their user entered values.